# Javascript setInterval "crashes" after a while?

Tags: javascript, raphael, intervals

I'm creating a 'bullet hell' style game, and have multiple setIntervals functions used to spawn enemies, one-ups, bullets, timers as well as setIntervals to measure collision between the different objects so it knows what to do (e.g. take damage, increase life etc). While the code works fine and all, after a while (I've tried running this multiple times, usually around 40-60s, though sometimes up to 5mins later), it essentially 'crashes' - my collisions don't work anymore, and the spawn intervals work like once every second. I've tried messing around with the setInterval timers but nothing seems to work, the entire code is fairly long so I've pasted it in a [pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/nhAsLmEA), any help is appreciated!

Otherwise, the intervals that are running are here:

```
let startGame = function(ev){
        bulletHellPopup.style.display = "none"
        if (isMouseUp === false && isEndlessOn === false){ //puting this in a conditional stops the spawnEnemy function from running multiple times
            isMouseUp = true;
            spawn = setInterval(spawnEnemy, 100); //manipulate this value to adjust spawn rate
            time =  setInterval(startTimer, 100)
            loadTime = Date.now();
        }; 
        if (isMouseUp === false && isEndlessOn === true){
            isMouseUp = true;
            spawn = setInterval(endlessSpawn, 150); //manipulate this value to adjust spawn rate
            time =  setInterval(startTimer, 100)
            loadTime = Date.now();
            spawnLivesVariable = setInterval(spawnLives, 10000);
            shootFunction = setInterval(spawnBullets, 75);
        }; 
    };
    let damage = function(ev){
        collision(playerCircle, bulletArray);
        //console.log(bulletArray.length)
    };

    let oneUp = function(ev){
        collisionLife(playerCircle, lifeArray);
    };

    let shooting = function(ev){
        collisionShoot(shootArray, bulletArray);
    };

    setInterval(damage, 50);
    setInterval(oneUp, 50);
    setInterval(shooting, 50);
```

Comment: You are experiencing what they call "layout thrashing".
Using ```setInterval()``` or ```setTimeout()``` to continuously make changes to the user's screen, causes it.
Read up on requestAnimationFrame, which can solve this for you. Possible reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/requestanimationframe.shtml

Comment: @KevinVerstraete, thanks for linking me to this! It was interesting to say the least. Unfortunately, though I have replaced my setInterval functions with requestAnimationFrame, the issues seems to persist, though it happens a bit later than if I were to use setIntervals. Also, not sure why but cancelAnimationFrame doesn't seem to work properly. Though it does make everything smoother, the underlying issue persists :(

Comment: I'm not a game designer, but I know the limitation of js and browsers. Everything in browser pages is a single thread so the more intervals and timeouts you use the heavier on the execution stack. So 1 or 2 interval/animationframe to rule it all seems a good idea. BUT read up on Web workers, this gives you access to multithreading in a browser. You could move the intervals there and send the events that require UI changes via events to the page. I know I only give small bits and pieces but like I said, not my core business.

Comment: @KevinVerstraete hey no worries, thank you so much for pointing me towards other interesting things I've yet to learn, I really appreciate it!